# Can I stop Google Goggles from automatically searching after OCR?

Tags: google-goggles

I recently had need to OCR a screenshot I had taken of my phone. I went to Google Play to find an app to do that, when I noticed that one of them was tagged "goggles". That reminded me of the [Google Goggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil) app, which I already had installed. So I decided to see whether or not Goggles would work on an image that had already been taken. I found that it could, and it did successfully OCR the portion of the image that I needed.

The annoying thing was that it, quite without my permission, took that OCR'd text and did a Google search on it. It had no reason do to that, and I'm glad I wasn't OCR'ing any really personal data. So my question is: Is there any way to stop Goggles from doing the automatic search, or should I look for another OCR app?

Comment: If the part you're concerned about is sending the data to Googles servers, that's most likely already done for the OCR itself. I doubt there are many apps out there which can do complete onboard (offline) OCR. Just try doing the OCR in airplane mode to verify, I might be wrong here.

Comment: I'd just like the option to copy numbers. I very rarely want to search, so to have this as default is pretty frustrating.